# Go Lang 1.8 server in Docker not listening on given port

Tags: docker, go

I have go lang micro service written in 1.8 , which run fine in local and I can hit api expose by service.
I have created docker image as follow..

```
FROM golang:1.8
WORKDIR /go/src/rt-services
COPY . .
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
CMD ["rt-services"]
```

I have started container like this
docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app my-golang-app

I can see logs up to this line of code

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080, httpHandler)
```

but I am not getting any response on locahost:8080 in browser and no error in logs also.
Not sure whats wrong here appreciate your help.

Comment: Wrap the listen and serve call with a `log.Fatal()` to catch any runtime errors. Possible port in use error - due to another service?

Comment: Does your software work when you start it outside docker? If it does, it's probably docker problem. Probably settiing up docker is a bit out of Stack overflows scope.

Answer (score 2):

you have to map the port on the host as well. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) concerning this topic.

In your case you can simply execute:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it --rm --name my-running-app my-golang-app
```

Comment: tried but got this error-- Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my-running-app (0c3b9dd7186edf4944351a8be8e6b6c9c5ec5282a43e0bc22edcdc48daa5d978): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8080:tcp:172.17.0.2:8080: input/output error.

Comment: on what OS are you? Windows?

Comment: Yes windows  10, I have another nginx container which work correctly with -p 8080:80

Comment: ah.... maybe that's the problem... you're mapping the port 8080 on both nginx and the go application. Only one application should be served per port. Delete/stop the other containers asking for the port 8080 and try again

Comment: @colminator: docker is failing to start not the application. If he'd execute the docker without the port mapping, the application would run without troubles. I don't think the `log.Fatal()` would change the log output in a meaningful way.